# Microsoft Visual Studio - The network path was not found

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code that connects to a SQL-SERVER but it always has an error **The network path was not found**

What should I do?

**I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class Registration
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=OnlineExamForInterns; Initial Catalog=tb_registration; User ID=LarryKrisya-PC\LarryKrisya")

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    sqlcon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=OnlineExamForInterns; Initial Catalog=tb_registration; User ID=LarryKrisya-PC\LarryKrisya")

    If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlcon.Close()
    End If

    Dim GetInternID As String = "select max(InternID) from tb_registration"
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(GetInternID, sqlcon)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    If DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim u As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(GetInternID, sqlcon)
        Dim y As SqlDataReader = u.ExecuteReader
        u.ExecuteReader()

        Label4.Text = y.Item(0)

    End If



End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Whats the connection string in web config look like or do you have one?

Comment: Here:


<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=LARRYKRISYA-PC;Initial Catalog=Test1;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it is not able to connect to your database. I am not sure if you are using windows authentcation to connection to sql server instance. But clearly your connection is flawed. If you are using sql server with logged in user login then what you need to do is following:

```
<add name="MyDbConn2" 
  connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

replace the values with your machine settings. For given your courrent settings it should look like following:

```
Data Source=OnlineExamForInterns; Initial Catalog=tb_registration; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

My solution assumes you are using your logged in windows user to connect to database. If you are using a username and password then you need to provide both with your connection string. And the user you are providing in your connection string should have access to your database ( you can configure that)

Comment: But, I dont remember my Username. Only my password.

Comment: I tried to re-install. Save the Instance ID. Then my password. But it always says, its wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your connectionstring says `data source=onlineexamforinterns`. Unless you have a sql server called onlineexamforinterns you're going to keep getting an error. this should be the network name for the sql server